# Why they choose mentally disabled person to disguise as Kala Bhairava?

Tags: shiva

In my village of south india, During days of Maha Shivaratri (Month: Feb).
Devotees choose one **Mentally disabled person(Males only)** & decorate him as Kala Bhairava & his hand holding sword with lemon pin at the top. They roam him around the streets. People pour yellow water at his feet when he reach their houses.

I am not sure name of the Avatar here, but definitely one of avatars of Lord Shiva.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE friend can you mention the Name of the Temple in your question to make it more clear for us to understand